# CakePHP script function in default.ctp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

How would I put this in my cakephp default.ctp file?

Im pretty novice at cakephp as ive just started using it.

```
     <script>
        $(function()
        {
          $('#slider-id').codaSlider();
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is too vague to answer in its current state, you should have a look at the JsHelper,especially Js->buffer(). This allows you to append script in your views and output them all at once in your layout.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#working-with-buffered-scripts

Comment: ok, what i want is to use codaSlider. before i used cake i just put this in <head>. I dont know the syntax to use it in cake.

Comment: In cakephp you can still add it to the head of your default.ctp. Have a look at the HtmlHelper for examples (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script). However, with questions like this, you should really just read the CakePhp manual (cookbook) to get started

Comment: ok i read through it properly and eventually got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. open the `app/View/Layout/default.ctp` file in your favorite code editor
2. add the following between your `<head>` and `</head>`:

> ```
>  <script>
>     $(function()
>     {
>       $('#slider-id').codaSlider();
>     });
>  </script></li>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2.x there are now things called blocks, and blocks are just chunks of output stored in memory until they are fetched for output.

There use to be a `$scripts_for_layout` variable that you could put your script into, but now we use the `$this->fetch('scripts');` to get any JavaScript needed for the Html.

There are a few ways to inject JavaScript into the `scripts` block using the [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3ascriptBlock).

To add it to the block, and this can be done in Views or Layouts. Just run this code before you fetch the block.

> $this->Html->scriptBlock("$('#slider-id').codaSlider();",array('inline'=>false));

To output the scripts in your layout is easy.

> $this->fetch('scripts');

The advantage of this approach is you can add JavaScript from multiple places in CakePHP, but they will be outputted in the layout at the location you desire.